# End space of non-compact 2-manifolds in terms of proper rays

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, surfaces, geometric-topology, compactification

I am wondering if the [classification of noncompact surfaces](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1963-106-02/S0002-9947-1963-0143186-0/S0002-9947-1963-0143186-0.pdf) given by Ian Richards can be stated with proper rays instead of nested sequences of connected open subsets with compact boundary. Below I deliver some definitions needed to explain my question.

Given a surface $\Sigma$ (i.e. a connected second-countable Hausdorff space locally homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$), a *pre-end* of $\Sigma$ is a nested sequence $\{U_{n}\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ of connected open subsets of $\Sigma$ with compact boundary such that for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, $U_{n+1}\subset U_{n}$ and for every compact $K\subset \Sigma$ there exists $l\in \mathbb{N}$ with the property that $U_{l}\cap K=\emptyset$.

Two pre-ends $\{U_{n}\}$ and $\{V_{n}\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ are **equivalent** if for any $i\in \mathbb{N}$ there exists $j\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $V_{j}\subset U_{i}$ and vice versa. The set of equivalence classes of pre-ends is denoted by $E(\Sigma)$ and its elements are the *ends* of $\Sigma$. A topology is given to $E(\Sigma)$ by specifying a basis as follows: for any open subset $W\subset \Sigma$ whose boundary is compact, a basic open subset of $E(\Sigma)$ is given by
$$W^*:=\{[U_{n}]\in E(\Sigma)\hspace{0.1cm}|\hspace{0.1cm}U_{l}\subset W \mbox{ for }l \mbox{ sufficiently large}\}.$$
The corresponfing topological space $E(\Sigma)$ is known as the *end space of* $\Sigma$.

A surface is said to be *planar* if all of its compact subsurfaces (possibly with non-empty *manifold* boundary) are of genus zero. An end $[U_{n}]$ is called *planar* if there exists $l\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $U_{l}$ is planar (equivalently, if there exists an open subset $W\subset \Sigma$ with compact boundary that is embeddable in $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $[U_{n}]\in W^*$).
Analogously, an *orientable* end can be defined.

Equivalently, the end space of $\Sigma$ can be described using proper rays (i.e. continuous maps $\gamma:[0,+\infty)\rightarrow \Sigma$ such that for every compact set $K\subset \Sigma$, the set $\gamma^{-1}(K)$ is compact as well) as follows: two proper rays $\gamma_{1}$ and $\gamma_{2}$ are *equivalent* ($\gamma_{1}\sim \gamma_{2} $) if for every compact $K\subset \Sigma$ there exist an $T>0$ such that $\gamma_{1}\big([T,+\infty)\big)$ and $\gamma_{2}\big([T,+\infty)\big)$ lie in the same path component of $\Sigma\setminus K$. In this setting, the end space of $\Sigma$ is the quotient
$$e(\Sigma):=\frac{\{\gamma:[0,+\infty)\rightarrow \Sigma\hspace{0.1cm}|\hspace{0.1cm}\gamma \mbox{ is a proper ray}\}}{\sim},$$ equipped with the topology determined by the following convergence notion (see User's answer below for a description of a basis of such topology): If $end(\gamma)$ is the equivalence class of a proper ray $\gamma:[0,+\infty)\rightarrow \Sigma$, then a sequence of equivalence classes $\{end(\gamma_{n})\}$ converges to $end(\gamma)$ if for every compact set $K\subset \Sigma$ there exists a sequence of positive numbers $N_{n}$ such that, for $n$ sufficiently large, $\gamma_{n}\big([N_{n},+\infty)\big)$ and $\gamma\big([N_{n},+\infty)\big)$ lie in the same path component of $\Sigma\setminus K$.

The two previous definitions give rise to homeomorphic end spaces. Indeed, on one hand, given a pre-end $\{U_{n}\}$, we can create a proper ray by picking points $x_n\in U_{n}$ and connecting $x_{n}$ with $x_{n+1}$ using a path entirely contained in $U_n$. On the other hand, if $\gamma: [0,+\infty)\rightarrow \Sigma$ is a proper ray, we can construct a pre-end $\{U_{n}\}$ for which $\gamma\big([n,n+1]\big)\subset U_{n}$.

My question is whether or not the space of ends seen as a quotient of proper rays can distinguish the planar ends and the orientable ends.

Comment: The standard way of defining topology on $e(\Sigma)$ is as follows: Write the equivalence class of a proper ray $a\colon [0,\infty)\to \Sigma$ as $[a]$. Let $C$ be a compact subset of $\Sigma$ and $A$ be a component of $\Sigma\backslash C$. The set $\big\{[a]\in e(\Sigma)\big|a(t)\in A\text{ for all sufficiently large }t\big\}$ is declared to be open and these sets form a basis for a topology on $e(\Sigma)$. See here https://www.google.co.in/books/edition/Topology_Conference/H_B6CwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=PROPER+HOMOTOPY+THEORY+IN+SIMPLICIAL+COMPLEXES+by&pg=PA41&printsec=frontcover

Comment: Though it is not too hard to show that $e(\Sigma)$ (with the topology mentioned in comment) is homeomorphic to $E(\Sigma)$, considering some special exhaustion of $\Sigma$ by compact bordered subsurfaces (see part (3) of the proof of Theorem 4 of  Richards paper). I don't know know how do you show the $e(\Sigma)$ with compact-open topology is homeomorphic to $E(\Sigma)$.

Comment: @User The topology you describe on the space of ends $e(\Sigma)$ is the correct one. I confused the Freudenthal boundary with the Gromov boundary in my description. I will make the correspondent edit.